# Finding ranges of continous values

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

With a MySQL table with timestamps.

```
|Timestamps             |
|-----------------------|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.000|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.100|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.200|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.300|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.600|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.700|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.800|
|2021-08-01 14:00:01.000|
```

I would like to get the time intervals of the continuous data. Continuous is defined by a frequency, in this example, it can be 10Hz
The desired result would be

```
|Start                   | End                    |
|------------------------|------------------------|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.000 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.300|
|2021-08-01 14:00:00.600 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.800|
```

I am using MySQL version 5.7.35
and cant use WITH and other functions. Can this be done fast?
There are ca. 100000 elements per table for now.

Comment: 10Hz  is 10 hour ?

Comment: @AliFidanli 10Hz == 0.1 seconds

Comment: Jep, 10Hz once every 0.1 seconds

Comment: I think you mean "contiguous".  See the tag I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
              my_data timestamp(3)  
                       );

INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.000'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.100'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.200'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.300'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.600'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.700'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.800'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:01.000');


SELECT 
       MIN(my_data) start,
       MAX(my_data) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN right(my_data,3) = @prev+100 THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+100 END row_num
            , @prev:=right(my_data,3) prev
         FROM test_tbl
            , (SELECT @prev:= null,@i:=0) vars 
              ORDER BY row_num
     ) x 
 GROUP  BY row_num;
```

Demo:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/98

Comment: I can't see how this works across .900 -> .000 that results in a break at every second shift, as I can see. but I may be able to use it anyways, I will return.

Answer (score 1):

After I got the first answer, I began to modify it and last night I got a working sample.

```
SELECT 
       MIN(my_data) start,
       MAX(my_data) end 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_data)*1000 >= @prev+90 and 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_data)*1000 <= @prev+110
      THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+100 END row_num
            , @prev:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(my_data)*1000 prev
         FROM test_tbl
            , (SELECT @prev:= null,@i:=0) vars 
              ORDER BY row_num
     ) x 
 GROUP  BY row_num;
```

I will mark the first answer, because it gave the inspiration. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

**Insert speed**

Rule of Thumb -- "Don't worry about performance if you are doing less than 100 writes per second." (You are asking about only 10/sec, correct?) (There are techniques to get past 100.)

**Non-windowing solution** (pre 8.0 or 10.2)

-- Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE gaps (
    ts timestamp(3),
    PRIMARY KEY(ts)    -- Some index on ts is important here
);

INSERT INTO gaps VALUES
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.000'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.100'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.200'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.300'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.600'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.700'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:00.800'),
('2021-08-01 14:00:01.000'),  -- By itself
('2021-08-01 14:00:01.300');
```

-- Add a sequence number (via AUTO_INCREMENT);
Caveat:  This depends on `auto_increment_increment = 1`

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS gaps2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE gaps2 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id) )
SELECT  val
    FROM (
        ( SELECT a.ts as val
            FROM gaps AS a
            LEFT JOIN gaps AS b  ON a.ts = b.ts + interval 0.1 second
            WHERE b.ts IS NULL
        )
        UNION ALL
        ( SELECT  b.ts as val
            FROM gaps AS b
            LEFT JOIN gaps AS a  ON b.ts = a.ts - interval 0.1 second
            WHERE a.ts IS NULL
        )
        ORDER BY val
         ) AS cd;
         
select * from gaps2;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | val                     |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.000 |
|  2 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.300 |
|  3 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.600 |
|  4 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.800 |
|  5 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.000 |
|  6 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.000 |
|  7 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.300 |
|  8 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.300 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

-- Pivot:

```
SELECT  CEIL(id/2) AS pair,
        MIN(val) AS 'run_start',
        MAX(val) AS 'run_end'
    FROM gaps2
    GROUP BY pair
    ORDER BY pair;

+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| pair | run_start               | run_end                 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|    1 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.000 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.300 |
|    2 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.600 | 2021-08-01 14:00:00.800 |
|    3 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.000 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.000 |
|    4 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.300 | 2021-08-01 14:00:01.300 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```